# How to upload an Image from iPhone, using SWIFT, to the Google App Engine blobstore?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to upload an image file, of .jpeg extension, to the GAE, i.e. running in python, but the problem is I'm supposed to send file data, but I'm unable to do that. Please help to solve this.

My code is

```
    body.appendData(("--" + boundary + "\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
                    body.appendData(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" + key + "\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
                    body.appendData(("Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
                    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
                    body.appendData(NSData(data: imageData))
                    body.appendData(("\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
```

Comment: Can we see you attempts?

Comment: @zellb please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding filename parameter to Content-Disposition

```
    body.appendData(("--" + boundary + "\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
                body.appendData(("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=" + key + "; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
                body.appendData(("Content-Type:application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
                var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
                body.appendData(NSData(data: imageData))
                body.appendData(("\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look over here [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:completionHandler:)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing content type from octet stream to image jpeg

```
body.appendData("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```